# Очерёдность выполнения запросов с MongoDB ReactiveStreams

Tags: java, многопоточность, mongodb

Впервые взялся за синхронизацию потоков и столкнулся с проблемой, что данные пытаются загрузиться быстрее, чем создаются (поток загрузки стартует быстрее).

Мне необходимо, чтобы `loadData()` вызывался только после того, как отработают все запросы из `regenerate()`.

За день перепробовал всё, что смог найти и довести до +- рабочего состояния:

- ExecutorService.
- synchronized (на объект, db и OperationSubscriber.class) на методах `loadData()` и `insertIfNotFound(...)`.

Подскажите, как без говнокода реализовать необходимый мне функционал, заранее благодарю.

```
public class DatabaseManager {
    ...

    public DatabaseManager() {
        reload();
    }

    /**
     * Переподключается к базе данных.
     */
    @SneakyThrows
    public void reload() {
        ...
        db = client.getDatabase(database);

        regenerate();
        loadData();
    }

    /**
     * Генерирует стандартные коллекции и значения, если их нет.
     */
    private void regenerate() {
        insertIfNotFound(
            "settings",
            Filters.eq("_id", "core"),
            "core",
            settingManager.getCoreSettings()
        );

        insertIfNotFound(
            "settings",
            Filters.eq("_id", "docker"),
            "docker",
            settingManager.getDockerSettings()
        );

        ...
    }

    /**
     * Загружает необходимые данные для старта ядра из базы данных.
     */
    private void loadData() {
            db.getCollection("settings")
                .find(Filters.or(
                    Filters.eq("_id", "core"),
                    Filters.eq("_id", "docker")
                ))
                .subscribe(new OperationSubscriber<>(documents -> {
                    documents.forEach(document -> {
                        ...
                    });

                    socketServer.bind();
                }));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Вставляет документ в коллекцию, если соответствующий фильтрам документ не найден.
     * Если коллекция не найдена - создают пустую коллекцию.
     * @param collectionName Название коллекции, в которой необходимо осуществлять поиск.
     * @param filter Фильтры искомого документа.
     * @param insert Объект, который будет вставлен, если документ не найден.
     */
    private void insertIfNotFound(String collectionName, Bson filter, Object insert) {
        insertIfNotFound(collectionName, filter, "", insert);
    }

    /**
     * Вставляет документ в коллекцию, если соответствующий фильтрам документ не найден.
     * Если коллекция не найдена - создают пустую коллекцию.
     * @param collectionName Название коллекции, в которой необходимо осуществлять поиск.
     * @param filter Фильтры искомого документа.
     * @param id ID, который будет иметь документ.
     * @param insert Объект, который будет вставлен, если документ не найден.
     */
    private void insertIfNotFound(String collectionName, Bson filter, String id, Object insert) {
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
        collection.find(filter)
            .subscribe(new OperationSubscriber<>(documents -> {
                if(documents.size() > 0) return;

                Document document = Document.parse(gson.toJson(insert));
                if(!id.isEmpty()) document.append("_id", id);

                collection.insertOne(document)
                    .subscribe(new VoidSubscriber<>());
            }));
    }
}
```

```
public class OperationSubscriber<T> implements Subscriber<T> {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Consumer<List<T>> callback;

    @Override
    public void onNext(T elem) {
        result.add(elem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        callback.accept(result);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        s.request(999);
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно подойдет CompletableFuture. Метод generate() сделать в supplyAsync, а loadData() в thenApply

Comment: @Revasha Благодарю за помощь :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой ответ просто из категории "многопоточное" программирование, т.е. возможно, библиотека Монго предоставляет более удобные инструменты.

```
    public void reload() {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(
            regenerate()
        ).thenRun(() -> loadData());
    }

    private CompletableFuture<Void> [] regenerate() {
        return new CompletableFuture<Void> []{
                insertIfNotFound(
                        "settings",
                        Filters.eq("_id", "core"),
                        "core",
                        settingManager.getCoreSettings()
                ),
                insertIfNotFound(
                        "settings",
                        Filters.eq("_id", "docker"),
                        "docker",
                        settingManager.getDockerSettings()
                )
        };
    }
    
    private CompletableFuture<Void> insertIfNotFound(String collectionName, Bson filter, Object insert) {
        return insertIfNotFound(collectionName, filter, "", insert);
    }
    
    private CompletableFuture<Void> insertIfNotFound(String collectionName, Bson filter, String id, Object insert) {
        final var done = new CompletableFuture<Void>();
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection(collectionName);
        collection.find(filter)
                .subscribe(new OperationSubscriber<>(documents -> {
                    if(documents.size() > 0) {
                        done.complete(null);
                        return;
                    }

                    Document document = Document.parse(gson.toJson(insert));
                    if(!id.isEmpty()) document.append("_id", id);

                    collection.insertOne(document)
                            .subscribe(new VoidSubscriber<>(() -> done.complete(null)));
                }));

        return done;
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь :3